# Android Shared Library Project Manifests

Tags: android, android-manifest, shared-libraries

I'm declaring a minSDK in my library project manifest and in my other project's manifest that utilizes the library project.  I am getting claim from a client that the apk will not install.

Here is the logfile they are reporting...

```
minSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest has two unique values – 0xa and 0x4 as shown below:
amolsMacBookPro:~ amundayoor$ aapt decode xmltree Desktop/AccuWeatherPlatinum-4493-application.apk AndroidManifest.xml | grep minSdkVersion
      A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0xa
      A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x4
```

Is the device reading both manifests?  I'm not sure how to read this.  Will declaring minSDK in only the launcher project work too?

Comment: I accidently had two declarations for minsdk in my manifest.  This caused the application not to install on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the manifest that your code is correct. I mean check the xml source (sometimes the graphical editor is out of sync with the source especially with the manifest.xml file)

Comment: Not sure what you mean here...I don't use the graphical editor. I cleaned both my projects prior to export the launcher project that utilizes the library to create apk.  The manifest in each has a declaration of minSDK of 4.